# How to download an ics file generated in PHP without using echo / print

Tags: php, http-headers, icalendar

I am creating some events on PHP and I'd like to download an .ics file containing these several events to upload them later on my for example, outlook calendar. With "print" or "echo" at the end it works fine but on the platform it is going to be used, I am not allowed to use these two functions. Is there an another way to output this event data?

What I have done so far is,

````
            $code = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
            $code .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
            $code .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
            $code .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
            $code .= "DTSTART:" . date("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($start_date_time)) . "\n";
            $code .= "DTEND:" . date("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($end_date_time)) . "\n";
            $code .= "LOCATION:" . $location . "\n";
            $code .= "TRANSP: OPAQUE\n";
            $code .= "SEQUENCE:0\n";
            $code .= "UID:\nDTSTAMP:" . date("Ymd\THis\Z") . "\n";
            $code .= "SUMMARY:" . $event['summary'] . "\n";
            $code .= "DESCRIPTION:" . $event['description'] . "\n";
            $code .= "PRIORITY:1\n";
            $code .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
            $code .= "BEGIN:VALARM\n";
            $code .= "TRIGGER:-PT10080M\n";
            $code .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\n";
            $code .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n";
            $code .= "End:VALARM\n";
            $code .= "End:VEVENT\n";
            $code .= "End:VCALENDAR\n";

            header('Content-type:text/calendar');
            header("Content-Description: File Download");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="events.ics"');
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header('Connection: close');
            print $code;
    ```
````

Comment: why you would not have print or echo? they are PHP functions, if you have PHP, you have those functions.

Comment: This piece of code is for an existing project and I am not allowed to use print or echo unfortunately. So I have been searching for ways to output the data in other ways.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php, then download the file?

Answer (score 0):

Since the framework builder was handling the outputs all I needed was to assign the part $code to the variable that is being outputted.

All your answers about using print or echo or downloading file were correct if someone needs to do this in the future.